# Invoke-WebRequest not downloading proper exe file

Tags: powershell-4.0

Using Powershell version 4.0 I'm trying to download Firefox browser programatically:

```ps
$uri = "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2"
$out = "C:\Users\bhatsubh\Downloads\Firefox Setup Stub 48.0.2.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $out
```

But it is not downloading the correct file. Instead the file is the wrong one with a size of 65 KB.

When I copy-paste the URL in the web browser the download starts automatically and the correct file is downloaded with a size of 237 KB.

[image: Two files which got downloaded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site uses javascript to start the download, so the wrong file you're getting is actually HTML page. Looking at its source we can see the actual link of setup "stub":

https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-stub&os=win&lang=en-US

It's also possible to download the full installer:

https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US

Comment: In situations like this , how i get to the correct download link ? Is there a way this can be done in windows ?

Comment: It depends on how the site implements it, so you'll have to look at the page source HTML and guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you:

Use this command: **Invoke-WebRequest $URL -OutFile 'c:\local-name.exe'**
The problem is with your URL. The url you are using is not the exact one pointing to original exe.
So For getting correct URL, follow below steps

1. Start downloading required exe and cancel that download in Chrome Browser
2. Goto downloads and right-click and click "Copy link adress" and set that value to $URL varible and retry. This works in most of the cases.